# Routing to multiple components on the same page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

Each section of my page is a separate component, which is located one after another while scrolling eg:

```
<sectionA></sectionA>
<sectionB></sectionB>
<sectionC></sectionC>
```

All the examples I've seen where creating routings to components on different pages, which where (in easiest words) clearing the container `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`  and filling it with the component assigned to given route.

What about the situation I've described, where all components are located on the same page and visible ?

How to set a proper route when scrolled to given section? The idea I have is to create a directive adding classes if sections are visible or not, and assigning a onscroll listener from the main module checking which section is currently visible and assigning the route respectively. Is this a correct approach?

How to link to a given section? Using regular `href=#sectionId` or the built in angular link directives?

Answer (score 1):

For this, you can use **name-router-outlet** as shown here

**DEMO: https://plnkr.co/edit/91YUcXI1la3B9dxzXSJp?p=preview**

**App.Component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector:"my-app",
  template:`
    <h3>Normal router-outlet</h3>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

    <hr>

    <h3>sectionA : named-router-outlet</h3>
    <router-outlet name='sectionA'></router-outlet>

    <hr>

    <h3>SectionB : named-router-outlet</h3>
    <router-outlet name='sectionB'></router-outlet>
  `
})
```

**app.routing.ts**

```
import { Routes,RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {HomeComponent} from './home.component';
import {SectionA} from './sectionA';
import {SectionB} from './sectionB';


let routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},

   { path: '', outlet: 'sectionA', component: SectionA},
   { path: '', outlet: 'sectionB', component: SectionB}
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Comment: Hey sorry for some questions but im not at home and don't know how to debug the routes on plunker. If I want the page to be scrolled on init to that component is it enough to set the path in the routing? Is my approach for setting the path on scroll proper? Or maybe you have some better, more natural "angular way" ?

Comment: I've found that to link to given section of the page I have to use the fragment option in the linking directive. But what about scrolling to the part of the page while adding a route?  eg.: if I want to go to `/sectionb` I want to load the page but be scrolled to that place

Comment: have you found a way to scroll to /sectionb etc?

Comment: @bogumbiker NOpe. I guess still it is an open issue in github.

Comment: @micronyks what do you mean open issue in github? which repo?